# tsql last "occurrence of" inside a string

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have got field containing comma separated values. I need to extract the last element in the list.
I have tried with this:

```
select list_field, LTRIM(RTRIM(right(list_field, len(list_field) - CHARINDEX(',',list_field))))
```

But it returns the last part of the list just starting after the first comma occurrence.
For example,

> a,b returns b
>
> a,b,c returns b,c

I would like to use a regex like pattern. Is it possible in TSQL (sql server 2008)?
Any other clues?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Find the last `,` by reversing the string and looking for the first occurrence, then read that many characters from the right of the string;

```
rtrim(right(list_field, charindex(',', reverse(list_field)) - 1))
```

(Use `reverse(list_field) + ','` if there is the possibility of no delimiters in the field & you want the single value)