# CASE Statement Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tasked with migrating my organization's Oracle SQL Views over to SQL Server. I am a novice when it comes to SQL, and have been unable to figure out the error I am getting from the CASE statement.

In the CASE statement, I want to read in the field's value, which will be a street address such as 123 Main St. The plan is to remove the 'St' substring from the field, and return '123 Main'

It already works in Oracle, I am just having difficulty converting the syntax into SQL Server, and the documentation on [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) have not helped me solve the problem. I'm probably overlooking something very simple.

The code is:

```
SELECT c.objectid, p.SHAPE, c.APN_PARCEL_NO AS prc_parcel_no, b.addr_status, b.addr_st_nmbr AS st_number, b.addr_st_frac AS st_fraction, b.addr_st_pfx AS st_prefix
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING (b.addr_st_name,  CHARINDEX( ' ', b.addr_st_name, -1) + 1) = 'ALY' 
    THEN SUBSTRING (b.addr_st_name, 1, CHARINDEX( ' ', b.addr_st_name, -1) -1)
  ELSE b.add_st_name
END
FROM dbo.PARCEL AS p INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_APN_PARCEL_LINK AS c ON p.PRC_PARCEL_NO = c.LAND_APN INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SITE_ADDRESS_ALL AS b ON c.APN_PARCEL_NO = b.prc_parcel_no
```

and the error I get reads:

> Error Source:.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> Error Message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

I apologize for any formatting problems, still learning how to properly write SQL. For your convenience, the CASE statement code in Oracle is:

```
CASE
             WHEN SUBSTR (b.addr_st_name,
                          INSTR (b.addr_st_name, ' ', -1) + 1
                         ) = 'ALY'
                THEN SUBSTR (b.addr_st_name,
                             1,
                             INSTR (b.addr_st_name, ' ', -1) - 1
                            )
   ELSE b.addr_st_name
          END st_name,
```

tl;dr - Looking to convert Oracle view to SQL Server, error is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: You need to put a comma before `CASE` (between `st_prefix` and `CASE`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'
```

In your statement, you have:

```
SELECT c.objectid, p.SHAPE, c.APN_PARCEL_NO AS prc_parcel_no, b.addr_status, b.addr_st_nmbr AS st_number, b.addr_st_frac AS st_fraction, b.addr_st_pfx AS st_prefix
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING (b.addr_st_name,  CHARINDEX( ' ', b.addr_st_name, -1) + 1) = 'ALY' 
    THEN SUBSTRING (b.addr_st_name, 1, CHARINDEX( ' ', b.addr_st_name, -1) -1)
  ELSE b.add_st_name
END
FROM dbo.PARCEL AS p INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_APN_PARCEL_LINK AS c ON p.PRC_PARCEL_NO = c.LAND_APN INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SITE_ADDRESS_ALL AS b ON c.APN_PARCEL_NO = b.prc_parcel_no
```

The `CASE` statement is a new column being returned, but right before it you do not have a comma separating the new column from the previous column:

```
...b.addr_st_pfx AS st_prefix /*Insert comma here*/ CASE ...
```

Granted, the error message isn't helpful, but at least it's specific: the error is "near `CASE`" in the sense that it's right before it.  There may be other issues, but that's the one referenced in the error message.

Another issue I can see is that the column name in the `ELSE` clause is misspelled: you have `add_st_name`, when it should be `addr_st_name`.

The `CASE` statement itself also looks like it has a problem with your conversion of `INSTR` to `CHARINDEX`.  `CHARINDEX`'s last parameter is the start position, but negative values are equivalent to 0: it starts at the beginning of the string.  Oracle's `INSTR` uses negative positions to search backwards.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9479899 for a technique to find the last occurrence of a character (in this case a space) in TSQL.

I think what you're trying to do is something like:

```
SELECT c.objectid, p.SHAPE, c.APN_PARCEL_NO AS prc_parcel_no, b.addr_status,
  b.addr_st_nmbr AS st_number, b.addr_st_frac AS st_fraction,
  b.addr_st_pfx AS st_prefix,
  CASE
    WHEN RIGHT(b.addr_st_name, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(b.addr_st_name)), 0) - 1) = 'ALY'
      THEN SUBSTRING(b.addr_st_name, 1, LEN(b.addr_st_name) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(b.addr_st_name)))
    ELSE b.addr_st_name
  END
FROM dbo.PARCEL AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_APN_PARCEL_LINK AS c ON p.PRC_PARCEL_NO = c.LAND_APN
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SITE_ADDRESS_ALL AS b ON c.APN_PARCEL_NO = b.prc_parcel_no
```

This strips off an ending of "(space)ALY" from `b.addr_st_name` if it exists.  Not too familiar with Oracle, but I think that's what your original statement was doing.

Comment: I attempted your suggested answer and get the error "Invalid column name 'add_st_name' 

Is this because I do not specify the column in the SELECT statement?

Comment: @csterling Must have seen it before my edit.  I saw the other part of your comment on sz1's answer and noticed you had a misspelled column name in your post that all of us have been copy/pasting.  I've fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tadmas! I'm getting a new error now - Invalid Length parameter passed to the RIGHT function. Looking into that function now...

Comment: @csterling Oh, yeah, um, I guess if there's no space in the value that will happen since the length ends up being -1.  I think you can wrap that in a `NULLIF` to fix it.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a comma before your `CASE` statement.

Also, on a side note, you might be able clarify the `CASE` statement like this:

```sql
SELECT c.objectid, p.SHAPE, c.APN_PARCEL_NO AS prc_parcel_no, b.addr_status, b.addr_st_nmbr AS st_number, b.addr_st_frac AS st_fraction, b.addr_st_pfx AS st_prefix,

       CASE SUBSTR (b.addr_st_name, INSTR(b.addr_st_name, ' ', -1) + 1)
         WHEN 'ALY'
           THEN SUBSTR (b.addr_st_name, 1, INSTR (b.addr_st_name, ' ', -1) - 1)
         ELSE b.addr_st_name
       END st_name,

  FROM dbo.PARCEL AS p INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_APN_PARCEL_LINK AS c ON p.PRC_PARCEL_NO = c.LAND_APN INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_SITE_ADDRESS_ALL AS b ON c.APN_PARCEL_NO = b.prc_parcel_no
```

*MSDN Reference on `CASE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx*

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma and a SUBSTRING character, I added the 1 (you will need to check what this should be) to the first SUBSTRING and the comma before the CASE statement.

```
SELECT c.objectid, p.SHAPE,
 c.APN_PARCEL_NO AS prc_parcel_no, b.addr_status, b.addr_st_nmbr AS st_number,
  b.addr_st_frac AS st_fraction, b.addr_st_pfx AS st_prefix,
CASE 
  WHEN SUBSTRING (b.addr_st_name, 1,  CHARINDEX( ' ', b.addr_st_name, -1) + 1) = 'ALY' 
    THEN SUBSTRING (b.addr_st_name, 1, CHARINDEX( ' ', b.addr_st_name, -1) -1)
  ELSE b.add_st_name
END
FROM dbo.PARCEL AS p INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_APN_PARCEL_LINK AS c ON p.PRC_PARCEL_NO = c.LAN
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be closer. The second argument SUBSTRING takes is START, that specifies where the returned characters start. If I am trying to get the last part of the string would I want to use -1?

I am also getting a new error after incorporating your code: Invalid column name 'add_st_name'   Am I getting this because I do not specify the column in the SELECT statement?

Comment: @csterling I think you're running into a difference between Oracle and SQL Server: in Oracle, negative position values index the end of a string; in SQL Server, negative position values index before the beginning of a string, so they usually end up equivalent to an index of 0.

Comment: @Tadmas So how would I specify the last index of a string in SQL Server?

Comment: @csterling See my answer - I linked to an answer on another question asking about that, and I also wrote a replacement that I think will work for you.